# How to get azure queue list with dead letter messages using namespace endpoint?

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Is there any way to get all the Azure servicebus queue names that have dead letter messages into a specific namespace using in C#.

I know that I can get all the queue descriptions using this:

```
IEnumerable<QueueDescription> queueList = namespaceManager.GetQueues();
```

How can I filter this list to only have queue names that have dead letter messages ?

Comment: you d like to get all the messages in all the dead letter queues of a specified namespace ?

Comment: no,i want the queue list which have dead letter queue of specified namespace

Comment: Every queue has a deadletter queue. You want the queue list where the deadletter queue is not empty ?

Comment: yes exactly...i want the queue list with dead letter messages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`NamespaceManager.GetQueues`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj835130.aspx) method allow you to get all queues in the service namespace with a specified `filter`:

```
var queues = namespaceManager.GetQueues("startswith(path, 'MyQueue') eq true");
var queues = namespaceManager.GetQueues("messageCount Gt 0");
```

Unfortunately, you can't filter on the `DeadLetterMessageCount` property.

Only solution I know is to get all the queue description and post-filter it :

```
var queues = namespaceManager.GetQueues()
    .Where(q => q.MessageCountDetails.DeadLetterMessageCount > 0);
```

Comment: I tried this: string filter = "MessageCountDetails.DeadLetterMessageCount Gt 0";   But it does not work.  :(    Glad I saw this to confirm my sanity.

Comment: PS  Boo Microsoft.